# install composer PHP Warning: file_get_contents(D:/software/PHP/php-7.1.1/extras/ssl): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, composer-php

Please help me. The following error occurred while installing composer.

The Composer installer script did not run correctly [exit code 1].

Script Output:
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(D:/software/PHP/php-7.1.1/extras/ssl): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Users\xhw27\AppData\Local\Temp\is-JBBHU.tmp\installer.php on line 1584

Comment: I use windows 10

Comment: Permission issue. are you using admin privileges?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?